# Alter Vaadin Dashboard theme to show SplitPanel splitter

Tags: vaadin

I am new to Vaadin and created a web application based on the Vaadin Dashboard theme. However, in my application I am using a VerticalSplitPanel but it does not show the splitter! It is impossible to resize the splitpanel.

After doing some research on the web, I found out that the Dashboard theme is limited in terms of styles of components since the theme only implements styles of components shown in the Dashboard demo application.

My question now is, is it possible to modify the Dashboard theme to allow styles for the splitpanel and thus allowing me to view the splitter? If yes, can someone give me a hint how and where I can do this (keep in mind I'm very new to vaadin!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashboard demo is really a nice startup to get some ideas for your app but i wouldn't suggest to use it as template to start your development on.
If what you are looking for is the "graphic look and feel" know that this feel is natively present in the Valo theme. For reference you can browse the Valo-Demo project on github ( https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo ): for exemple the left menu css styles are in the css of Valo, they are only modified in the dashboard demo.
If what you are interest in is the functionality of the "dashboard" page (there you see the sparks, the charts, notes and so on) keep in mind that is made with a CssLayout, which is a powerful way to make custom layouts but of course you have to work out everything.
Probably a SplitPanel inside this layout gets something overwritten or not everything is implemented in the css.
In the end you can try PortalLayout add-on in Vaadin directory to achieve something similar or add the missing styles by yourself.
Cheers.